# Printing gwt widget

Tags: gwt, printing

Can anyone tell me how to print gwt widget?

I gont through the folowing thread and tried .

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/eea48bafbe8eed63

Still I cant do that.I can able to print the widget without any css style.I want to include the css styles(css files) also.Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Perhaps there's another way to achieve what you need

Comment: @sinelaw- I cannot answer for your first question. It depends on my project requirement. Better please post your alternate way to solve this problem.

Comment: The exemple from Google groups is really good. I advise you to use media="print" if you want to print pictures. But don't forget that many browsers, by default, have an option that disable printing background image (eg in firefox : File > Page settings > Options > Print background (color and pictures)). There is no way to override this option with a tricky css or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar situation using the same link you have used.
It prints String, Widgets,Or Elements without any problem.

Solution I found is that you need some delay before you call Print.

So, There are few alternate solutions.
1. Write down a loop which causes delay of 2-3 seconds.
2. Use Time to get delay of 2-3 seconds
3. Use Window.Confirm to ask some question like 'Do you want to print ?'

Hope this will help to others

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class and on click of Print button in your application, by using native print method you can call Window.Print().

GWT UIObject can be used for this purpose and the method and it will be converted into string.

```
public class NTPrint {
    /**
     * If true, use a Timer instead to print the internal frame
     */
    public static boolean USE_TIMER = true;

    /**
     * Time in seconds to wait before printing the internal frame when using Timer
     */
    public static int TIMER_DELAY = 1;

    public static native void it() /*-{ 
        $wnd.print(); 
    }-*/; 

    public static void it(String html) {
        try{
            buildFrame(html);
            if (USE_TIMER) {
                Timer timer = new Timer() {
                    public void run() {
                        printFrame();
                    }
                };
                timer.schedule(TIMER_DELAY * 1000);
            } else {
                printFrame();
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable exc) {
            CommonUtil.printStackTrace(exc);
            Window.alert(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called when you pass Widget without style.
     * @param uiObjects
     */
    public static void it( UIObject...uiObjects) { 
        StringBuffer objString= new StringBuffer();
        for(UIObject obj: uiObjects)
                objString.append(obj.toString());
            it("", objString.toString()); 
    }
```

}

**OnClick of Print button,**

```
  /**
         * prints all forms
         * @param documentInfo
         */
        public static void printForms(List<FormTransaction> formTransactions, String documentInfo, List<CellTransaction> cellTransactionList, boolean isComment, Document document) {
                String style = "<link rel='styleSheet' type='text/css' href='v4workflow/css/style.css'>"
                                + "<link rel='styleSheet' type='text/css' href='v4workflow/css/gwtcontrols.css'>"
                                + "<style type='text/css' media='print'>"
                                + "@media print {"
                                + ".footerText{font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;margin-top:0px;}"
                                + ".break {page-break-after:always}"
                                + "}" + "</style>";
                List<UIObject> uiObjects = new ArrayList<UIObject>();
                NTPrintLayout printLayout = new NTPrintLayout();
                printLayout.setSelectedDocument(null);
                uiObjects.add(createHeader());
                NTPrint.it(style,uiObjects);
        }

 public static FlexTable createHeader(){
                FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
                flexTable.setWidth("100%");
                return flexTable;
        }
```